# Can't call functions needed for VBO implementation...not declared error

Tags: c++, opengl-es, blackberry-10

Hi I want to use `VBO` in my native application for `bb10 (C++)`. I want to call functions like `glBindBufferARB`. But It says

> `glBindBufferARB was not declared in this scope`

I am using opengl-es 1.1. I can call `glBindBuffer` function though.

**EDIT :** I included these header files

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>
```

Comment: Have you included the correct header file?

Comment: Hi I edited my answer with the inclusions. I already drawn a picture in the screen. But now I am trying to draw a picture with VBO.

Comment: Well, open the header files and find out what it's really called:)

Comment: How do I find that out from the header files? I don't know what the function is called in the header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glBindBuffer` is a standard OpenGL ES 1.1 function, so maybe try calling it without the `ARB` suffix.

> version 1.1.12 (April 24, 2008), § 2.9

```
void BindBuffer( enum target, uint buffer );
```

<sub>GL specs don't use `gl` prefix, but you have to</sub>

Comment: I can call `glBindBuffer` fine. But I cant and wanto call `glBindBufferARB` function and other like this to implement VBO. Thanks.

Comment: No, you don't want to. `glBindBufferARB` is the extension function, but this extension (VBOs) was put into core, so it's exactly what you want to do. These functions are exactly the same. Also, you are not *implementing* VBO, you can be merely using them. Know the difference.

Comment: Yes. I am using it. Not a native English speaker :) So `glBindBuffer` works exactly as `glBindBufferARB`. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi another question. If I create two VBOs. Suppose I bound the first one with its id and copied the data and drew it. And then comes the second one and I also bind it and copy the data and draw it. Now if I want to draw the first one again do I need to bind it again? If I need to bind again do I need to copy the data to buffer for that VBO again also?

Comment: If you want to ask another question, then *ask another question*. Comments aren't meant for that.

Comment: Can you please give an answer to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310777/vbo-doesnt-drawing-anything

Comment: @kalkin This is not a _thread_, it's a _question_. Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: Umm maybe it sounds silly but what is it if its not a forum. I always thought of it as kind of forum.

Comment: @kalkin [Something like this](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877705441970c-pi)