# VBO doesn't draw anything

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, opengl-es-1.1

I am trying to draw a square with VBO in my native blackberry 10 application. My implementation is,

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glGenBuffers(1,&decompressTileImage->VBOId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,decompressTileImage->VBOId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(tileCoordList)+sizeof(tileTextureCoordList),0,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,sizeof(tileCoordList),tileCoordList);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(tileCoordList),sizeof(tileTextureCoordList),tileTextureCoordList);

    glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(tileTextureCoordList), (void*)sizeof(this->tileCoordList));
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(tileCoordList), 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    swapBuffers();
```

Here tileCoordList contains the co-ordinates for the square and tileTextureCoordList contains the corresponding texture. `tileCoordList` is a `Square3D` type structure.

```
typedef struct
{
 Vertex3D lowerLeft;
 Vertex3D lowerRight;
 Vertex3D upperLeft;
 Vertex3D upperRight;
}Square3D;

typedef struct
{
GLfloat x;
GLfloat y;
GLfloat z;
} Vertex3D;
```

4 `Vertex3D` represents a square in tileCoordList. Same goes for `tileTextureCoordList`. I can draw fine without the VBO though. I am using opengl-es 1.1

Another question.

If I create two VBOs. Suppose I bound the first one with its id and copied the data and drew it. And then comes the second one and I also bind it and copy the data and draw it. Now if I want to draw the first one again do I need to bind it again? If I need to bind again do I need to copy the data to buffer for that VBO again also?

Comment: What exacly are the types of `tileCoordList` and `tileTextureCoordList`? Show their declarartions.

Comment: they are `Square3D` type structures. The declarations are in the question. Thanks.

Comment: No, your code wouldn't compile if they were. If the code compiles, they are either arrays of `Square3D` or pointers to `Square3D`, or you decided to leave out a few `&`s in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry.Yes they are square3D type pointer.

Comment: In that case, your `sizeof`s are all wrong, as those are only the size of the pointers, not the size of the structs.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right!! I cant test it right now though. Can you please make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has transpired in the comments that `tileCoordList` and `tileTextureCoordList`are pointers to `Square3D` structures.

This means that the `sizeof` operator will give you the size of a pointer, not the size of the struct.

You could use e.g.

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(*tileCoordList), tileCoordList);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something weird to your buffer. Without knowing what `tileCoordList` is it's hard to say if you are adding the data correctly.

In general, regarding both of your concerns here: VBOs store the data for you. It is not only possible, but encouraged to do:

```
vbo_1, vbo_2;

vbo1.LoadData(data_1);
vbo2.LoadData(data_2);

main_loop {
    vbo1.Bind();
    Draw();
    vbo2.Bind();
    Draw();
}
```

I have used pseudocode here, but you should get the idea. I don't understand what the `SubData` call is supposed to do; in general, one simple `glBufferData` should be enough. `Bind` call sets the buffer as an active one.

This line made me cringe - why is `VBOId` public? Smells like a poorly designed abstraction to me:

```
glGenBuffers(1,&decompressTileImage->VBOId);
```

And oh, *please* don't use `this->`. The only thing it does here is worsen readability.

Comment: `tileCoordList` contains 4 `Vertex3D` structures. `Vertex3D` has 3 `GLfloat` elements in it. They are x,y,z co-ordinate of one of the four points of a square. So 4 `Vertex3D` represents a square in `tileCoordList`. Same goes for `tileTextureCoordList`. I can draw with them without using VBO. And I thought it should be simpler and understandable if I use `glBufferSubData` to add the vertex co-ordinate and texture co-ordinates separately. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: uh, did you want to stride them in one VBO?

Comment: Yeah I wanted to add them in one VBO and added separately.

Comment: `BufferData` and `BufferSubData` can only handle contiguous data, IIRC. You will have to create your own temporary buffer and then copy everything at once.

Comment: `tileCoordList` started adding from 0 address with size of `sizeof(tileCoordList)` and `tileTextureCoordList` started adding from `sizeof(tileCoordList)` with size of `sizeof(tileTextureCoordList)`. I thought it was contiguous as I am adding contiguously in memory of the buffer.

Comment: So it is not strided. You should read [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices).

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I think I am following the (VNCVNCVNCVNC) format to store VBO data. But I don't understand whats striding means here. I coded the above code by reading this tutorial http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html I downloaded the code provided there. and did exactly the same as the code.

Comment: You need to read more about it because explanation is out of scope for this answer