# What is stride in glVertexPointer, glTexCoordPointer in VBO

Tags: c++, opengl-es, vbo, blackberry-10, stride

Hi I have a problem drawing with VBO. So I asked a question a [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310777/vbo-doesnt-drawing-anything) .I could not find the answer of my problem. But by discussing one answer given there I have now another question about strides in VBO. I am confused about what it is and does.

In [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/189323-vbo-stride-question/)  I found someone answered

> If you have all your vertex data in one array (array : read as
> malloc''ed pointer), all your normals in another array, etc. Then your
> stride is 0. For instance if vertex, normals, etc are stored like that
> :
>
> [vertex0][vertex1][vertex2]...
>
> [normal0][normal1][normal2]...
>
> [texcoord0][texcoord1][texcoord2]...
>
> If your vertex, normal, etc is packed like that :
>
> [vertex0][normal0][texcoord0][vertex1][normal1][texcoord1][vertex2][normal2][texcoord2]...
>
> Then you should set a non-null stride, which corresponds to the offset
> needed to switch from one element to the next. (this stride is counted
> as bytes btw)

From that explanation I thought the stride actually means the distance between end of one vertex and the start of another vertex in the buffer. In the first case its 0 because all the vertexes are stored contiguously. Same goes for the textures. But then I read another answer about the definition of strides in that same thread.

> There tends to be a bit of confusion regarding VBO stride, mostly
> because of its special meaning for 0.
>
> "Stride" in this context means the distance between the beginning of a
> value in memory, and the beginning of the next value in memory. It is
> not the distance between the end of one and the beginning of the next.
> So in a VBO that is an array of a structure, the stride for each
> element of that structure will be the sizeof the structure as a whole.
> Keep in mind that struct padding can affect this.

which just says the opposite of what the other answer says. Or I am wrong about what the first answer meant? Can anyone please help me solve the problem. I will really appreciate if anyone can give an answer with example. I have given the link of my implementation of VBO in the start of this question which is not solved yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the first answer is *trying* to say is that the "stride" between two elements is the offset in bytes between the beginning of one element and the beginning of the next.
*However*, if the elements you're passing are contiguous (i.e. there's no space between them), you can pass 0 for the stride parameter.

I would say that it's wrong to claim that "stride is 0" in this case - the stride *is* `sizeof(element)`, but the value 0 gets special treatment and is taken to mean `sizeof(element)`.
This is most likely done so the poor programmer doesn't have to use two (bug-prone) `sizeof` parameters in the common case when they are the same.

Comment: what does the word `offset` means? I see it used many times in many places. But none gave the definition of it. Thanks.

Comment: what will be the stride value if I store like this "vertex,texture,vertex,texture". What will be the stride value in `glVertexPointer` and `glTexCordPointer`?

Comment: @kalkin Offset means more or less the same as distance.

Comment: @kalkin In that particular case, the stride would be `sizeof(vertex) + sizeof(texture)`, because that's the distance from the beginning of one vertex (or texture) to the beginning of the next.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Its clear now :) Can you please look at my original problem? Its driving me crazy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310777/vbo-doesnt-drawing-anything